# Does 莫過於 require 最 for first noun?

Tags: grammar

[*ABC Chinese–English Comprehensive Dictionary* (2003)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABC_Chinese%E2%80%93English_Dictionary), p 629.

[image]

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%8E%AB%E9%81%8E%E6%96%BC) also defines this "nothing can surpass ..." Wikipedia's two sentences use 最.

I screen-shot [5:16](https://youtu.be/Belwm7u6J-k?t=316). I know 痛苦莫過於生存 means "nothing is more painful than existence". 鄭詩君 on the left said this. But 鄭詩君 didn't use 最. Is he wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In theory, we don't need 最 in '痛苦莫過於生存' because 莫過於 (no greater than) already indicated 'the most'.

However, "最X 的Y 莫過於Z" is a common structure of speech. For example 最危險的任務 莫過於 卧底行動  (the most dangerous task is the undercover operation/ no operation is more dangerous than an undercover operation)

- 最 emphasizes the topic
- 莫過於 emphasizes the object in the comment (or you can simply say 最危險的任務是卧底行動)

*I don't agree with this statement. Life itself is neutral. It can be full of happiness or sadness, and the way 鄭詩君 said it is not quite the standard way*

Comment: 鄭詩君 said this as joke or satire, if you watch the context.